# StoreKit Sandbox Testing Doesn't Prompt to Log in

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm testing an in-app purchase which *did* work fine a week ago, but now seems to be playing up.

I can load the product from the store without any problems (using NSLog to confirm the product id, price etc...), but when I send the actual request to purchase the product - I don't get challenged to log in to my (test) user account, it just returns an error code -1003 "Cannot connect to iTunes store".

This is strange because it *did* work a week ago, and now it doesn't. What's weirder is that it does prompt me for my password (to purchase the product) if I am currently logged into my live iTunes account.

It's almost as if the app is checking to see if there is an iTunes account logged in, and if not it will just fail... which is rather annoying as you're not supposed to log into the test accounts via your settings as it will invalidate it.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me? I'd be well chuffed if you could :)

Thanks!

Comment: I've been getting this for several days as well - suggest reporting the issue to bugreport.apple.com as they've clearly changed something or accidentally broken something they may not be aware of yet.

Comment: Hah - so I just tried that and got a nice Times New Roman, red text error: An error has occurred. Please report the error to Apple Inc. by emailing the error detail to devbugs@apple.com. Geeze.....

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue as well. You may want to try one or all of these steps.

1. Delete the app from your device and rebuild it.
2. Log out from any iTunes account on the device.
3. Delete the app. Reboot your device and build and run again.
4. Log into the iTunesConnect portal and view your test user page.

I have been able to reconnect by doing one or all of these things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Logging out of iTunes on my device worked for me.  Didn't have to delete app, or reboot the device.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by creating a new test user. My guess is the test account accidentally saw the live store - which tends to kill them. Might be your problem as well?

Comment: Well, the thing is - it's not even prompting me for my test user credentials - therefore it doesn't even know about that user. Even so - I did still give this a go, to no avail. Thanks anyway.